# How to create a horizontally scrolling data table using datatables.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I am attempting to format my table using DataTables, however I can't seem to get it working properly.  I searched stack overflow, youtube, and the DataTables website for solutions and I have tried everything that I have found but still haven't gotten the result I'm looking for, particularly a horizontal scroll bar.  I am very new to html and javascript so any help would be much appreciated.

Here are some of the changes I have tried, but there are many more I cannot remember.

1. using scrollX: true instead of "sScrollX" : "100%
2. setting the style tag of the table to style="overflow-x:auto;"
3. Removing the divs before the table

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#recon-table').DataTable({
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "110%"
            });
        });
    </script>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Recon Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box-transparent">
        <div class="box-content table-scroll-box">
            <table class="display nowrap" id="recon-table" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Date of Birth</th>
                        <th>Language</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>
                        <td>somet@email.com</td>
                        <td>1234567890</td>
                        <td>uname</td>
                        <td>English</td>
                        <td>Male</td>                            
                    </tr>                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is the issues, your missing a td tag line for the DOB column, just add that and it should work like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollX: true,
  });
});
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Date of Birth</th>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>somet@email.com</td>
      <td>1234567890</td>
      <td>uname</td>
      <td>01-June-1982</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope this helps